# Change vs Replace Engine Oil (HELP)

Tags: hyundai, oil-change, santa-fe

So I own a 2018 Hyundai Santa Fe Sport and I was looking at the maintenance schedule provided. In the document it shows they mention change engine oil and filter for some mileages and in other mileages it tell to replace engine oil and filter. My question is what is the difference between changing engine oil and replacing engine oil? I am so confused.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

What's the difference?

### Absolutely nothing.

More than likely if you are seeing this in two (or more) places in the manual, different people wrote it. Really, it's just semantics.